# Sitecore 7.2 MVC and DMS

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.2

I am trying to setup DMS on Sitecore 7.2 using MVC. I am able to set personalization rules via the Page Editor but  the rules do not run when I view the page as a normal users. I have checked the following:

1. Analytics.Enabled is set to true
2. @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() has been added to the main layout
3. The analytics DB is setup
4. No errors are showing in the logs.
5. I have enabled the config file Sitecore.MvcAnalytics.config
6. analytics is enabled for the site.
7. My conditions work in WebForms, it is only MVC that doesn't work.

We have narrowed the problem down to Controller Renderings, our solution works for View Renderings. Has anyone made personalisation work with Controller Renderings? We have replicated this problem in a vanilla SC instance.

Here is a video of our problem:

http://screencast.com/t/1nGwUINJLZO

This is a screenshot of my controller code:

[image]

And the components on the page:

[image]

We have tried to setup a test with the minimum amount of interference.

Comment: Is there a particular type of rule that does not run? Or is it that none run?

Comment: If you add a quick "println" sort of statement into your view, can you output the current user's information to see if it is indeed resolving the visitor identity?

Comment: Just to be sure, are the following configs in include folder:

1- Sitecore.Analytics.config
2- Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config

Also, Do you get any restult from running this SQL query:
SELECT * FROM [Pages]

Comment: Data is getting to the DB

Comment: We have narrowed down the problem to controller renderings.

Comment: May be problem is caused by wrong way of getting datasource. How do you get personalized datasource in controller renderings?

Comment: While I did find [a bug with MVC & A/B testing](https://github.com/BenGGolden/Sitecore.Mvc.TestingHotfix), I don't have any issues with personalization.  Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @Michael i was able to reproduce this on sitecore 7.2 (LaunchSitecore instance), this seems to be a bug as sitecore does not resolve data source based on Personalization rules for Controller rendering, you might need to contact Sitecore support

Comment: @AhmedOkour We have contacted support as well but I am surprised no one else has come across this. Thanks for confirming that it isn't just me doing something wrong. I will update this if support get back to us.

Comment: Data source resolution in this particular case happens during @Html.Sitecore().Field(). It will grab either Rendering.Item or PageContext.Current.Item if the former returns null. I blogged about it just last week on jockstothecore. Rendering.Item goes through a number of steps to give you the item one of which is resolving your rendering's datasource. In order to troubleshoot it further (and I asked Mike on twitter) I would need to see the controller rendering definition item (with standard fields) and the controller code

Comment: @MichaelEdwards, I guess what I am saying is - make sure you are not sending the razor view through yet another rendering pipeline (e.g. if you wrapped it in a RenderingView it would). If you did, it would have its own RenderingContext and its own Rendering object that won't have the datasource personalized. The datasource is personalized on your controller rendering object. You basically need to keep the RenderingContext intact for your razor view to pick up the right Item (i.e. personalized DataSource) in the @Html.Sitecore().Field().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The problem was caused by the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config file. I hadn't mentioned WFFM in my original question because I assumed that it wouldn't affect DMS.

When you enable DMS without WFFM the getRenderer pipeline looks like this:

```
<mvc.getRenderer patch:source="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.config">
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.CustomizeRendering, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.MvcAnalytics.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetViewRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetItemRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetXsltRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetControllerRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetMethodRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetUrlRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetDefaultRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
</mvc.getRenderer>
```

You can see here that the first entry is a processor that analytics inserts to control personalisation. If we now enable the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config this pipeline changes to this:

```
<mvc.getRenderer patch:source="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.config">
    <processor type="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.GetFormControllerRenderer, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.CustomizeRendering, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.MvcAnalytics.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetViewRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetItemRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetXsltRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetControllerRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetMethodRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetUrlRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetDefaultRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
</mvc.getRenderer>
```

Notice that the WFFM Forms MVC entry inserts itself at the start of the pipeline. This causes problems because it returns a rendering:

```
protected override Renderer GetRenderer(Rendering rendering, GetRendererArgs args)
{
  if (args.Rendering.RenderingItem.ID != IDs.FormMvcInterpreterID)
    return base.GetRenderer(rendering, args);
  Tuple<string, string> controllerAndAction = this.GetControllerAndAction(rendering, args);
  if (controllerAndAction == null)
    return (Renderer) null;
  string str1 = controllerAndAction.Item1;
  string str2 = controllerAndAction.Item2;
  FormControllerRenderer controllerRenderer = new FormControllerRenderer();
  controllerRenderer.ControllerName = str1;
  controllerRenderer.ActionName = str2;
  return (Renderer) controllerRenderer;
}
```

The CustomiseRendering processor then does nothing because there is a returned result, therefore no personalization is performed:

```
public override void Process(GetRendererArgs args)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
  if (args.Result != null || args.Rendering == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Rendering["RenderingXml"]))
    return;
  CustomizeRenderingArgs args1 = new CustomizeRenderingArgs(args.Rendering);
  args.Result = PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<CustomizeRenderingArgs, Renderer>("mvc.customizeRendering", args1, (Func<CustomizeRenderingArgs, Renderer>) (pipelineArgs => pipelineArgs.Renderer));
}
```

## Cause:

This is caused by the order that the MVC, Web Forms and Analytics configs are loaded. By default they are loaded in this order:

1. Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config
2. Sitecore.Mvc.config
3. Sitecore.MvcAnalytics.config

This is the correct order.

## Solution:

The solution is to rename the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Config to y.Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.config to force it to be loaded last.

Comment: It would also be great if WFFM configs were in a subfolder so they would process after all standard product configs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it can be specific to controller renderings to be honest. In Sitecore MVC controller and view renderings alike follow the same pipeline path. More specifically, a variation based on A/B (aka MVT) test or personalization rules is picked as a first step in `mvc.getRenderer` pipeline. You should have

```
Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.CustomizeRendering
```

in there coming from `Sitecore.MvcAnalytics.config`. When it runs it will trigger `mvc.customizeRendering`. I guess what I am saying is - **Personalization happens *before* a particular renderer is picked based on your rendering's type**. You may want to look at `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.Personalize` in `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics` to see how exactly Sitecore applies your personalization rules.

I know I am not answering your question per se but here's what I would do myself:

- Make sure the rendering in question runs its natural course (e.g. you are not creating a `Rendering` object on which you set `.Renderer` manually, not *monkey patching* MVC contexts, etc.)
- Confirm the outer rendering (in case your controller rendering is *nested* within another rendering) is not set to be cached (if it is, Sitecore won't call the rendering pipeline on the inner renderings again once the outer rendering has been cashed. I know it's obvious but I've seen people surprised by it)
- Double check that personalization rules are recorded just like you think they are by inspecting the raw value of the item's `__Renderings` field in the published item (personalization doesn't run in `Preview`, only runs when `PageMode.IsNormal`).
- Make sure you are not sending the razor view that ends up generating markup through yet another `renderRendering` pipeline when you return from your controller. If you wrap it with `RenderingView`, for example, it would run through its own pipeline and would have its own `RenderingContext` and its own `Rendering` object. Personalization will change the datasource on your controller rendering object and your `@Html.Sitecore().Field()` may be talking to a different `Rendering.Item` than you need (log your `Rendering.Item` in your controller and do the same in your razor to see what's going on). I blogged about some of it last week (http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-mvc-item-maze/) and you will probably see the rendering pipelines sequence if you Debug in Page Editor.
- If everything looks right and rules still mysteriously don't fire I would most likely use the trick I learned very recently and would put Sitecore in debug (http://bilyukov.com/debugging-sitecore-dotpeek/). Helped more than once to get to the bottom of things.

Answer (score 0):

I can not get the @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() to work. We just put the

```
<sc:visitoridentification runat="server" />
```

before the

```
</head>
```

Have you looked at your source to see if @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() includes it?

Comment: The `sc:` is a control that you would use in a WebForms layout. The `@Html` is a razor helper that you would use in an MVC layout. You can't really mix the two together or expect that one be used by the other (well, technically, you can have an interop between the two rendering engines but your answer suggests a direct dependency. And that's probably why you couldn't get the `@Html` to work ... on an `.aspx` page. Try it on a `.cshtml` with Sitecore MVC)

Comment: Thanks, we only use mvc. I know you should not use it, but we had to use it to get the analytics running. I searched a bit and found out that you have to include @using sitecore.mvc.analytics.extensions to get it working from a friendly soul, but no documentation from Sitecore :). We will try that.